# Determine whether the given map ϕ is an isomorphism of the first binary structure with the second.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether the given map ϕ is an isomorphism of the first binary structure with the second.

⟨ℤ,+⟩ with ⟨ℤ,+⟩ where ϕ(n)=n+1 for n an element of ℤ

Can someone please provide me a detailed proof showing it is 1-1,onto and homomorphic. 
This is what I have so far, but I am very confused.

let x1,x2 be elements of ℤ then ϕ(x1)=ϕ(x2) then x1+1=x2+1 then x1-x2 thus it is 1-1? is this step correct?

Comment: The question asks you to determine if it's an isomorphism, not prove it is one necessarily. Do you think it is an isomorphism? Why or why not?

Comment: I know from the answers this one is not but I wanted to try going through the proof and then showing why one of the criteria doesn't hold..

Comment: Hint: is $\phi(1+1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1)$?

Comment: Or even consider if $\phi(0)=0$ is true.

Comment: honestly I'm not sure...

Comment: @Lil what do you get when you try to "work it out"?

Comment: so the function tells you to take what is in the parentheses and one to it correct?

Comment: so the left would be 3 and the right would be 4?

Comment: That's right..so: does $3 = 4$?

Comment: no. Alright so I understand how to show a homomorphism now. Thank you!

Comment: Can I just walk through how to prove its onto and 1-1 so I can try to do other problems?

Comment: was this correct? let x1,x2 be elements of ℤ then ϕ(x1)=ϕ(x2) then x1+1=x2+1 then x1-x2 thus it is 1-1?

Comment: That's not right, but you have the right idea. Suppose $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$. Then $x +1 = y + 1$. Subtracting $1$ from both sides, $x = y$, so $\phi$ is 1-1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21560/discussion-between-david-wheeler-and-lil).